# How to use /scoreboard to have a list of names on the sidebar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a prison and 3 levels: Guards, prisoners and Receptionist. I want to display a list of everyone in those groups and add different colours them. How would I achieve this? 
Example...

```
Guards:
teddy9264
diamond_knight1

Prisoners:
Minecraft_Player77
A_Prisoner

Receptionist:
Minecraft_Player99999
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What have you tried to acomplish this on your own? It is easier to answer your question if we know what you tried so far.

Comment: Is this text static or do you want to dynamically create the list?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Sorry everyone, been away but back now... it is static. Thanks for your response

Comment: I have made teams, made an adjective then added the players to the list then I made it go on the side. but it only comes up with the team name not the people in the team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible using Vanilla Minecraft, although you could do something like it:

/scoreboard objectives add playerlist dummy Players
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Players

Then, on a clock:

/scoreboard players set @a playerlist 1

This won't be perfect, but it should be enough for what you want to do, and if you have colored names for players on teams, it will display the colors as well.